# Adding a thumbnail/icon to a newsletter

Tags: email

When you receive an email, you usually get the first letter of the sender as an icon on the left side, right? Well I was wondering how I would be able to change this icon when sending a newsletter (see example below - the newsletter was sent using MailChimp).

[image: example]

Comment: Do you want to change the icon as a sender of the email, or as the receiver of the email?

Comment: As a sender of the email (I'd like the logo of the company to be shown when I send out the newsletter, basically)

Comment: You can't. That's based on the photo attached to the contact in the receiver's contact list.

Comment: @AlEverett You might want to post that as an answer. :)

Comment: Not that I've tried, but it would seem to make sense that if you create a Google+ profile for the email address, then that profile pic would be used. Could be worth trying?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Mystic Medusa" isn't on the contact list though. @GAThrawn That's a very interesting suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images come from your Gmail contacts so you would need to create a contact for the "The Nudge" and assign a picture to it. To easily create a new contact for that email, open it up and click the icon next to the name. You should then be prompted to "Add  to contacts?".